# custom rule validation not working-Yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2, custom-validators

can you help me with this? I did read the docu but the rule is still not working. Did I done it wrong? I still searching for some examples but still nothing happened. I want to validate a user's password and repeat_password if they match.

this is my code in model.
that two are declared as required too on that scenario.

```
[['password','password_repeat'], 'checkPassword', 'on'=>'create'],
```

the scenario is declared on actionCreate too.

```
public function checkPassword($attributes, $params)
    {
        if(!$this->password_repeat === $this->password)
        {
           $this->addError($attribute, 'Passwords do not match!');
        }
    }
```

I did try using `compare` validation on that two fields but it won't satisfy me. If you only compare one field, it won't validate the other field. if you validate them both, there's still a possibility that they contrast each other when you delete what you have entered on one of the two fields. So I want to create one that even you delete what you have enter on that two fields, who goes first or not, they will be validated. sorry for the trouble. I hope you still get what I want to happens. Thanks.

PS, I don't want to use a password validator widget(?). thank you.

Comment: Hint: in your code you have a parameter `$attributes` which should be `$attribute`.

Comment: @robsch still nothing, tho. it didn't trigger the validation

Comment: Your condition is wrong ! it should be `$this->password_repeat !== $this->password`

Answer (score 2):

You Just Use This Validation in your `model` file like...

```
['password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password_repeat',  'message' => 'Your error message'],
```

Comment: can I use that with `when` validator? I'm still unsatisfied with `compare` validator. @bvp

Comment: you just use your scenario in controller file

Comment: $model->scenario = 'create';

Comment: `$model= new Users(['scenario' => 'create']);` this is the code in my controller

Answer (score 0):

In your code.

```
$this->addError($attribute, 'Passwords do not match!');
```

Check your varname $attribute, it does not exist in your function declaration.

```
public function checkPassword($attributes, $params)
```

AddError can't assign the error to a form-field.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```